# Stored Procedure returns exception in .net but runs fine in sql server c# winforms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, stored-procedures

Why does the following stored proecedure cause problems in .net c# its basically used for the nature of a report of benefits on screen readonly it works fine in sql server when i tick pass null value for start date and end date but when try to do the same on my adapter fill below it throws an exception

procedure :

```
    public virtual EmployeeBenefitDataset GetBenefitsRecords(int id)
            {
                try
                {

                    EmployeeBenefitDataset ds = new EmployeeBenefitDataset();
                    using (BenefitTableAdapter adpt = new BenefitTableAdapter())
                    {
                        adpt.Connection.ConnectionString = DataAccessLogicHelper.PamsConnectionString;

                        adpt.Fill(ds.BenefitRecords, id, 4, null,null);
                    }
                    return ds;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.ErrorEntry(ex);
                    throw ex;
                }
```

stored proecdure

```
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[hms_GetBenefitRecordsDetails]    Script Date: 09/09/2013 14:09:42 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[hms_GetBenefitRecordsDetails]
    (
        @empno int,
        @type int,
        @stardate datetime,
        @enddate datetime

    )
    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
      IF NOT @stardate IS NULL
     begin 
     SELECT     benefit.emp_no, benefit.record_id, benefit.contract_id, benefit.career_id, benefit.date_from, benefit.date_to, benefit.benefit_type, benefit.monthly_value, 
                          benefit.benefit_provider, benefit.level_of_cover, benefit.previous_monthly_cost, benefit.benefit_change_details, benefit.current_benefit, benefit.notes, 
                          benefit.level_description, benefit.monthly_annual, benefit.cover_level, benefit.qualifying_reason, benefit_cover_level.desc_ AS benefitcoverdescription, 
                          benefit_provider.desc_ AS benefitproviderdescription,benefit_type.desc_ as benefittypedescription ,employee.benefit_annual_amount,employee.benefit_salary_option,employee.benefit_value
    FROM         benefit INNER JOIN                      
                          benefit_cover_level ON benefit.cover_level = benefit_cover_level.code INNER JOIN
                          benefit_provider ON benefit.benefit_provider = benefit_provider.code INNER JOIN
                           benefit_type ON benefit.benefit_type = benefit_type.code
                           INNER JOIN employee on benefit.emp_no = @empno
                           where benefit.emp_no= @empno   or employee.emp_no= benefit.emp_no
                          and  benefit.benefit_type = @type
     end 
     else
     begin 
     SELECT     benefit.emp_no, benefit.record_id, benefit.contract_id, benefit.career_id, benefit.date_from, benefit.date_to, benefit.benefit_type, benefit.monthly_value, 
                          benefit.benefit_provider, benefit.level_of_cover, benefit.previous_monthly_cost, benefit.benefit_change_details, benefit.current_benefit, benefit.notes, 
                          benefit.level_description, benefit.monthly_annual, benefit.cover_level, benefit.qualifying_reason, benefit_cover_level.desc_ AS benefitcoverdescription, 
                          benefit_provider.desc_ AS benefitproviderdescription,benefit_type.desc_ as benefittypedescription ,employee.benefit_annual_amount,employee.benefit_salary_option,employee.benefit_value
    FROM         benefit INNER JOIN                      
                          benefit_cover_level ON benefit.cover_level = benefit_cover_level.code INNER JOIN
                          benefit_provider ON benefit.benefit_provider = benefit_provider.code INNER JOIN
                           benefit_type ON benefit.benefit_type = benefit_type.code
                           INNER JOIN employee on benefit.emp_no = @empno
                           where benefit.emp_no= @empno   and employee.emp_no= benefit.emp_no


     end 

      IF NOT @stardate IS NULL
     begin 
     SELECT     benefit.emp_no, benefit.record_id, benefit.contract_id, benefit.career_id, benefit.date_from, benefit.date_to, benefit.benefit_type, benefit.monthly_value, 
                          benefit.benefit_provider, benefit.level_of_cover, benefit.previous_monthly_cost, benefit.benefit_change_details, benefit.current_benefit, benefit.notes, 
                          benefit.level_description, benefit.monthly_annual, benefit.cover_level, benefit.qualifying_reason, benefit_cover_level.desc_ AS benefitcoverdescription, 
                          benefit_provider.desc_ AS benefitproviderdescription,benefit_type.desc_ as benefittypedescription ,employee.benefit_annual_amount,employee.benefit_salary_option,employee.benefit_value
    FROM         benefit INNER JOIN                      
                          benefit_cover_level ON benefit.cover_level = benefit_cover_level.code INNER JOIN
                          benefit_provider ON benefit.benefit_provider = benefit_provider.code INNER JOIN
                           benefit_type ON benefit.benefit_type = benefit_type.code
                           INNER JOIN employee on benefit.emp_no = @empno
                           where benefit.emp_no= @empno   and employee.emp_no= benefit.emp_no and
                          benefit.benefit_type = @type and 
    benefit.date_from >= @stardate and benefit.date_to <= @enddate
    end
```

Comment: @Gerrie Schenck Its a constraint exception but dont understand why .net throws an erro and sql server does not ?

Comment: @davidb, you have been asked several times what the exception is. I can't understand why you haven't show it... it's madness! If you want this community to fix your problem, then show us *exactly* what it is.

Answer (score 1):

When you select the checkbox to pass null values, then it explicitly pass the `NULL` values alongwith the parameters. In your current code, you are not even passing the parameters that is why the exception.

In current form your stored procedure is not ready to accept `NULL` values for startdate and enddate, you should modify your procedure as:

```
@stardate datetime  = NULL, 
@enddate datetime = NULL
```

For passing `NULL` `DateTime` from C# use `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`, which supports `Null` values.

Comment: that did not solve it im afriad still getting an exception this worked before fine when didnt have the dates on the procedure so no it works spot on

Comment: @davidb, what is the exact exception you are getting, is it like the procedure expected parameter `X` which was not provided.

Comment: do you have example for when i try        adpt.Fill(ds.BenefitRecords, id, 4, DateTime?, DateTime?);
             the compiler does not like it ?

Comment: @davidb, oh NO NO, not like that. How are you attaching the command object with the adapter ?

Comment: no i not sure how to do that its my first fory into the adpaters and ef look above how i am doing it

Comment: this is using the enitty frame work so not sure how to do that myself

Comment: @davidb, IMO entity framework is something that should have been mentioned before in the question, did you try to refresh your schema after modifying the SP ?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum and maximum dates that `SQL` and `C#` use are different... this *could* account for you 'only .NET' error. These are the minimum and maximum values that `SQL` can handle:

```
private DateTime minSqlValue = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
private DateTime maxSqlValue = DateTime.MaxValue.AddMilliseconds(-3);
```

Please check the dates that are being used and update them if they are outside this range.

Comment: we are usuing 1/1/1990

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, the problem is that ADO.NET see you passed an null value, which it has as a `System.Object`, to call a procedure for a SQL Server DateTime parameter, which it will try to map to `System.DateTime`, not `System.Nullable<System.DateTime>`. Because `System.DateTime` is not nullable, it will take `default(DateTime)` to send to the procedure. `default(DateTime)` in .NET is "01/01/0001 00:00:00.00", which does not match SQL Server's minimum DateTime value

Change your stored procedure to use DateTime2.

Comment: and do you have example how i pass this then to the fill?

Comment: Just change your stored procedure to use the type datetime2 instead of datetime. The SQL server type datetime is not very good. Unless you have very specific reasons for using any of the other date types, you should almost always stick to datetime2.